# Extracting city information only from OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, osm2pgsql, overpass-api

I need to extract City as well as hierarchy of admin entities for selected countries.

My understanding for now is that I'll have to get `node`  primarily and find a clever filtering based on tags. And possibly include some `ways` as they are often used to represent administrative boundaries.

I also need to store these info in a specific database design in Postgresql.

Would `osm2pgsql` be the most adapted tool to filter out information and directly import in my db design?

Or would `overpass` be necessary anyway to do the filtering because I feel it'd would be a much more powerful tool in this regards?

I'd then need to program import to DB based on received data, but I'm not even sure `osm2pgsql` would be flexible enough to import in my design.

Comment: thanks for the editing @PolyGeo